# Securing a Spring Boot which has just had endpoints exposed

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud

I've just been playing around with Spring Boot and developed a small Spring Cloud Streams app which basically acts as a destination for incoming messages through a queue.

However, I wanted to expose a health check endpoint so that I can verify if the service is up and running.

Until now, `spring.main.web-application-type` has been `none`. However, tu run `actuator` I must have that on.

I want to think that having the previously mentioned property to none didn't make the service exposed to the outside world and now that it has been enabled I must check and prevent some kind of accesses?

Are there any security concerns I must check now?

Comment: How and where are you deploying your app and do you need to access the health endpoint over the internet or a specific network?

Comment: @MadhuBhat thanks for the reply! App is going to be deployed within a container, and will have to be restricted to access over a specific network, ideally it shouldn't be exposed outside.

Comment: And you need to access the health-check endpoint within the container or outside it?

Comment: @MadhuBhat outside the container but within the same network yeah.